# How do Americans pronounce "it would", "it was", etc.?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, consonants

How do you pronounce "it would", "it was", etc. in American English? That is, how do you pronounce the T when it precedes a semi-vowel such as "w"? Is there a stop T or not when the words are pronounced fast?

I know, when followed by a vowel, it's a flap T (as in "it is"), and, when followed by a consonant, it's a full T (as in "it looks"). Yet, I can't put my finger on this.

Comment: What do you mean by Full-T? I doubt that's what's used in *it looks*.

Comment: "It looks" sounds like a stop T.  By full t I mean the T as in twirl, tweak etc

Comment: A lot of times the *it* would be omitted and so the *t* not pronounced at all: *Looks like some weather coming in*.

Comment: Say "it would" or "it was" or whatever very slowly and distinctly, then say it more and more rapidly.  What happens?

Comment: I asked this ages ago as I was still carefully studying the phonetics of the language. I'm happy to say it was not unsuccessful. The t here is not pronounced. There's some kind of stop there following the initial vowel, but there's no 't'. (I'm specifically saying this with 'standard' North American English in mind. Someome somewhere might of course pronounce it differently)

Comment: Can someone convert ih-twood and ih-twuhz to IPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many dialects, /t/ before a consonant (including w) is pronounced [ʔt] or even [ʔ], that is, [glottalized or preglottalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-glottalization).

(*Edit to clarify: that is, /t/ before a consonant, except for initial /t/ which is not glottalized.*)